# Adjust the Grid and row and column setting in Tkinter height dose not match

Tags: python, tkinter, position, size

I am using Grid manager to align the logframe at the right side in my program with my left side tracing method so that they can be at the same height.
 I already try to adjust the height of logframe, reset the position of the column but this also doesn't work,Any suggestion can improve my coding also can give me as well,regards.

This is the image:

[image]

Here is the code i use to set the logframe

```
def logDetails(self):
    self.logframe = LabelFrame(self,text="Log Details",height= 450,width =390,padx=15)
    self.logframe.grid_propagate(0)

    self.logframe.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight =1)
    self.logframe.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

    xscrollbar = Scrollbar(self.logframe,orient = HORIZONTAL)
    xscrollbar.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=E+W,columnspan=2)

    yscrollbar = Scrollbar(self.logframe)
    yscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=N+S)

    text = Text(self.logframe,width=50,height=60, wrap=NONE, xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set, yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)
    text.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2)
    # attach listbox to scrollbar
    xscrollbar.config(command=text.xview)
    yscrollbar.config(command=text.yview)

    button_1 = Button(self.logframe, text="View", command=printMessage)
    button_1.grid(row=2,column= 1)

    button_2 = Button(self.logframe, text="Export", command=printMessage)
    button_2.grid(row=2,column= 2)

    self.logframe.grid(row=0,column =1,rowspan=5)
```

Full coding it will be very helpful to solve this question:

```
from tkinter import *
class TracingInterface(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        root.minsize(width=700, height=500)
        root.maxsize(width=700, height=500)
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        Grid.config(self)
        self.TracingMethod()
        self.logDetails()
        self.otherFunctionInterface()

    def TracingMethod(self):

        self.traceMethodSelect = StringVar()
        self.traceMethodSelect.set("LT")

        self.radioframe = LabelFrame(self,text="Tracing Method",height= 120,width =300)
        self.radioframe.grid(row= 0, column=0)
        self.radioframe.grid_propagate(0)

        self.radioframe.LT= Radiobutton(
        self.radioframe, text="Live Tracing",
        variable=self.traceMethodSelect, value="LT",
        anchor=W).grid(row=1, column = 0, sticky = W,columnspan=2)
        self.radioframe.SL= Radiobutton(
        self.radioframe, text="Specific Location",
        variable=self.traceMethodSelect, value="SL",
        anchor=W).grid(row=2, column = 0, sticky = W,columnspan=2)

        self.traceButton = Button(self.radioframe, text="Trace")
        self.traceButton.grid(row =3, column =0, sticky = W)

        self.cancelButton = Button(self.radioframe, text="Cancel")
        self.cancelButton.grid(row =3, column =1, sticky = W)

        self.configUAButton = Button(self.radioframe, text="Configuration")
        self.configUAButton.grid(row =3, column =2, sticky = W)
        self.configUAButton.config(width=15)

        self.browseButton = Button(self.radioframe, text="Browse")
        self.browseButton.grid(row =3, column =3, sticky = W)

        location_ent =Entry(self.radioframe)
        location_ent.grid(row =2, column = 2, sticky = W,columnspan=1)
    def logDetails(self):
        self.logframe = LabelFrame(self,text="Log Details",height= 450,width =390,padx=15)
        self.logframe.grid_propagate(0)

        self.logframe.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight =1)
        self.logframe.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

        xscrollbar = Scrollbar(self.logframe,orient = HORIZONTAL)
        xscrollbar.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=E+W,columnspan=2)

        yscrollbar = Scrollbar(self.logframe)
        yscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=N+S)

        text = Text(self.logframe,width=50,height=60, wrap=NONE, xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set, yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)
        text.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2)
        # attach listbox to scrollbar
        xscrollbar.config(command=text.xview)
        yscrollbar.config(command=text.yview)

        button_1 = Button(self.logframe, text="View", command=printMessage)
        button_1.grid(row=2,column= 1)

        button_2 = Button(self.logframe, text="Export", command=printMessage)
        button_2.grid(row=2,column= 2)

        self.logframe.grid(row=0,column =1,rowspan=5)

    def otherFunctionInterface(self):
        self.otherFrame = LabelFrame(self,text="Other Function",height= 400,width =300)
        self.otherFrame.grid(row=4, column=0)
        self.otherFrame.grid_propagate(0)

        OpenPreviousCaseFile = Button(self.otherFrame, text="Open previous Case File", command=printMessage,height = 4, width =25)
        OpenPreviousCaseFile.grid(row=5,column= 0,pady=5)

        OpenPreviousTracingResult = Button(self.otherFrame, text="Open previous Tracing Result ", command=printMessage,height = 4, width =25)
        OpenPreviousTracingResult.grid(row=6,column= 0,pady=5)

        OpenMenualbtn = Button(self.otherFrame, text="User Manual", command=printMessage,height =4, width =25)
        OpenMenualbtn.grid(row=7,column= 0,pady=5)

        AboutBtn = Button(self.otherFrame, text="About", command=printMessage,height = 4, width =25)
        AboutBtn.grid(row=8,column= 0,pady=5)

def printMessage():
    print("Wow this actually worked!")
root = Tk()
root.title("Windows User Activity History Tracing and Analysing System")
tif= TracingInterface(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I just found the solution:
adjust the logframe height to 520 and the root max & min height set to 520 as well.

Comment: To make them resize appropriately (rather than hardcoding heights) you can give `sticky` more than one argument strung together- i.e. `sticky=N+S+W` will make the thing stick to the left side, while filling all the vertical space for the cell(s) it occupies.